# Populate select tag with data from API in Vue and Axios

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I want to populate *select tag* with data from api get request. Here is my html code

```
<div id="app">
    <label for="country" class="control-label">Country</label>
    <select v-model="selectedCountry" @change="onChangeCountry" name="country" id="country" class="form-control" tabindex="11">
        <option selected disabled value="">Please select one</option>
        @foreach($countries as $country)
            <option value="{{ $country->id }}">{{ $country->name }}</option>
        @endforeach
    </select>
    <label for="city" class="control-label">City</label>
    <select v-model="cities" name="city" id="city" class="form-control" tabindex="12">
        <option v-bind:value="city.id">@{{ city.name }}</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

And now my JavaScript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    new Vue({
      el: '#app',
      data: {
        selectedCountry: '',
        cities: []
      },
      methods: {
          onChangeCountry: function (event) {
            axios.get('http://localhost:8000/api/cities/country/' + this.selectedCountry)
            .then(function (
                this.cities = response.data
            }).catch(function(error) {
                console.log('an error occured ' + error);
            });
          }
        }
    });
</script>
```

I'm pretty sure that the data is received because i did a lot of console.log but I don't know how to append the received data to my second select tag nor how to proceed.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: In your comments below, you have responded several times with the report that "it doesn't work". Please note that this is the least helpful response you can give a contributor. You are the eyes and ears on the problem, and it is your job to be as clear and verbose as you can. Consider these things: how did it not work? What did you observe? Were there any logs or errors, or did it partly work? What information can you send to the helpful person trying to help you, without any prompting?

Comment: i don't know what's happening, the select tag that i want to fill is still empty after so many attempts, and there is no errors in console

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally got it working
i just needed to create a city variable in data function
and in select i don't need to bind it to array of cities[], the city variable is fine **v-model="city"**

Comment: Can't see how that is actually different than what i answered

Comment: At the first i was biding to the array of cities using v-model but then i bind it to a single city object. I don't really get it because i'm a newbie to vuejs

Answer (score 5):

Try this in the select

```
<select v-model="selectedCity" name="city" id="city" class="form-control" tabindex="12">

   <option v-for="(city,cityIndex) in cities" :key="city.id" :value="city.id">{{ city.name }}</option>

</select>
```

Add 'selectedCity' to the data object and then access its value through this.selectedCity

This is in the vue docs

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html#Select

Comment: still doesn't do anything

Comment: what does the axios request object returns?

Comment: an array of objects(the city object)

Comment: i don't know what's happening, the select tag that i want to fill is still empty after so many attempts, and there is no errors in console

Comment: One thing that is confusing me is that you're using Vue and trying to use v-model, but on the same page you have a blade foreach. Please elaborate on the structure that you're using

Comment: If you're using vue as a dom altering library, what both me and @btl sugested might not workk since you're not using vue as we thought you are. You might need to use vue to manipulate the DOM which is more common to do with something like jQuery

Comment: well I want to use Vue to perform a HTTP get request
the first select is filled with records from database and my second select is empty by default and i want fill it with Vue since it can handle XHR alongside with axios
i know you both tried everything but I'm still stuck
It's my first time with Vuejs but I'm pretty advanced with laravel + angular

Answer (score 1):

```
<select v-model="country" class="form-control">
   <option disabled value="" selected="selected">Please select one</option>
   <option v-for="country in countries" :key="country.id" v-bind:value="country.id">
           {{country.name}}
     </option>

</select>
<script>
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            countries: {},
            country:''
    } 
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `v-for` to loop the cities and create the option elements:

```
<select name="city" id="city" class="form-control" tabindex="12">
    <option v-for="(city, index) in cities" 
            :key="index" 
            :value="city.id">@{{ city.name }}
    </option>
</select>
```

Also, change your `data` property into a function so it's reactive:

```
 data () {
    return {
      selectedCountry: '',
      cities: []
    }
 }
```

Comment: Updated the answer

Comment: still doesn't do anything

Comment: do you want any other details
i believe everything is clear but why is this happening to me ?

Comment: What does `console.log(response.data)` show? Can you include the output in your answer?

Comment: (2) [{…}, {…}]0: {id: 4, country_id: 4, name: "West Cortney", created_at: "2018-02-28 13:21:41", updated_at: "2018-02-28 13:21:41"}1: {id: 6, country_id: 4, name: "Ceceliaton", created_at: "2018-02-28 13:21:41", updated_at: "2018-02-28 13:21:41"}length: 2__proto__: Array(0)
11:23:17.800

Comment: it doesn't work either
i don't know what's happening, the select tag that i want to fill is still empty after so many attempts, and there is no errors in console